# Visualizing Azure Templates in Visual Studio

Tags: azure

Can someone please let me know if its possible to visualize azure templates https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates using Visual Studio?

At present templates can be visualized using http://old.armviz.io/#/ However, I would like to view the templates using Visual Studio if possible?

Kind regards

Carlton

Comment: Huh what? We generally don't use Visual Studio for anything. That's a developer tool, is it not?

Comment: Hi Micheal, you can do everything with Visual Studio that can you do with Azure portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can author ARM Templates in Visual Studio after installing the SDK, but there's no graphical representation like Armviz.

Download the .NET Sdk:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

Comment: Bruno, you answered my question... I have the .NET but I was hoping Visual Studio or some other application had a graphical representation like Armviz

Comment: Great! Unfortunately no, but JSON Outline tab makes editing ARM Template projects quite easy in VS. Don't forget to accept it as an answer if it worked for you :)